# Fe(II) and Fe(III) transport from rhizosphere across plasma membrane

Tags: botany, plant-physiology

Does the graminaceous plants have passive uptake of Fe(II) via a passive Fe(II)-transporter enzyme? Or it it only dicots and non-graminaceous plants that have the Fe(II)-transporter enzyme? Also, can Fe(III)-reductase reduce Fe-EDDHA (*Ethylenediamine-N,N'-bis(2-hydroxyphenylacetic acid)*) and Fe-DPTA (*diethylene triamine pentaacetic acid*) without the cost of energy?

Best regards,

Mathias